# adding filters into the search query in elasticsearch using NEST client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

here's my get request for the filter query

```
GET  demosearch/_search
{
   "query": {
       "filtered": {
          "query": {
          "match_phrase": {
             "material": "shirt"
          }
          },
          "filter": {
              "term": {
                 "colorId":"31"
              }
          }
       } 
   }
}
```

now i need to write this query in c# using nest client i have tried something like this but it's not working for me

```
var res1=client.Search<nextDocument>(s=>s.Analyzer("automplete")
                .From(0).Size(20)
                     .Query(f=>f.Filtered(c=>c
                         .Query(v=>v.MatchAll())
                         .Filter(b=>b.
                             Term(l=>l.CategoryId)))));
```

Please help me with this Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MatchPhrase` method

```
.Query(q => 
    q.MatchPhrase(m =>
        m.OnField(f => f.Material)
            .Lenient()
            .Query("shirt"))  
    && q.Term(t => t.ColorId, 31)));
```

Also, you can run your query as a string using `QueryRaw` method

```
QueryRaw(queryString);
```

Comment: now if i want to implement multiple filters @Valentin how to achieve that?